# Call adviced method from around advice and avoiding infinite loop without using cflow

Tags: java, infinite-loop, aspectj, pointcut

I want to capture all method executions in com.ABC.MyClass using AspectJ

```
 package com.ABC
 
 public class MyClass{
       
        public methodA(){
        }

        public methodB(){
          methodA();
        }
 }
```

Below is the Aspect :

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect{
  @Pointcut("execution(* com.ABC.MyClass.*(..))")
  public void captureMyClassMethods(){
  }
  
  @Around("captureMyClassMethods()")
  public Object aroundMyClassMethods(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable{
    MyClass object = (MyClass)jp.getTarget();

    object.methodA();      //This causes infinite loop

    Object o = jp.proceed();
    System.out.println("Some data from o");
    return o;
  }
}
```

As mentioned in comments in around advice, while calling methodA() from advice is causing infinite loop.

As mentioned in another stackoverflow answer [Aspectj - how to call advised method from within same advice, without triggering an infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641283/aspectj-how-to-call-advised-method-from-within-same-advice-without-triggering)  if I change the pointcut expression below then I would miss capturing execution of methodA() when it is called from methodB() because it will be in aspects control flow.

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.ABC.MyClass.*(..)) && !cflow(within(MyAspect))")
```

Another way I can think of is using before and after advices instead of around advice. But I want to know if there is a way to handle this with around advice?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I am answering because your question presents a nice puzzle, not because I think that your use case is particularly relevant. Probably, it is rather a design flaw. I think, you should not try to call a method from an advice which is targeted by the same advice.

Both your variant `!cflow(within(MyAspect))` and something like `!adviceexecution()` would, as you have noticed, preclude internal method calls from being captured.

The workaround is an [`if()` pointcut](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html#d0e3697) and keeping state in a static, thread-local, boolean field, which is ugly and potentially slow. But if it works for you, you can do that.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.hello();
    myClass.world();
    myClass.helloWorld();
  }

  public String hello() {
    return "Hello";
  }

  public String world() {
    return "world";
  }

  public String helloWorld() {
    return hello() + " " + world() + "!";
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

import de.scrum_master.app.MyClass;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  public static ThreadLocal<Boolean> calledFromAdvice = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> false);

  @Pointcut("execution(!static * de.scrum_master.app.MyClass.*(..)) && if()")
  public static boolean captureMyClassMethods() {
    return !calledFromAdvice.get();
  }

  @Around("captureMyClassMethods() && target(myClass)")
  public Object aroundMyClassMethods(ProceedingJoinPoint jp, MyClass myClass) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(jp);
    try {
      calledFromAdvice.set(true);
      myClass.helloWorld();
    } finally {
      calledFromAdvice.set(false);
    }
    String result = (String) jp.proceed();
    System.out.println("  " + result);
    return result;
  }
}
```

The `!static` qualifier avoids the static `main` method from beiong intercepted. There, the target object would be `null`, causing a null pointer exception when trying to call amethod upon it.

Please also note how I am binding the target object to an advice parameter, which is more elegant than calling `jp.getTraget()` and casting it.

Last but not least, the `try-finally` makes sure to always reset the flag, even if there is an exception while calling `hello`.

The console log looks like this:

```
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.MyClass.hello())
  Hello
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.MyClass.world())
  world
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.MyClass.helloWorld())
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.MyClass.hello())
  Hello
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.MyClass.world())
  world
  Hello world!
```

As you can see, in this case the inner method calls inside `helloWorld` are both captured correctly, but there is no stack overflow exception due to calling `hello` from the aspect